# Filter data between two dates - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to obtain data using django filter and connected to postgres database.
The filter statement leads to error- 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)'

Here is the sql equivalent and my attempt at creating a django filter query
You would notice that I have used two columns for storing datetime, review_time_datetime  and match_time_datetime

SQL Equivalent QUERY

```
SELECT *
    FROM "table1" where review_time_datetime  >'2021-06-14 00:00'
    and match_time_datetime < '2021-06-14 24:00'
```

Django Filter QUERY

```
filter_query = table1.objects.filter(review_time_datetime, match_time_datetime)
```

Comment: Use the [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup: `query.filter(review_time_datetime__range=(datetime1, datetime2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
filter_query = table1.objects.filter(review_time_datetime__gt=from_date, match_time_datetime__lt=to_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this to lookup

```
import datetime
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Table1.objects.filter(review_time_datetime__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

Read more https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#range